# Maze Generator getting stuck in certain areas

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

```
int x = Random.Range(0, n);
        int y = Random.Range(0, n);
        met[x, y] = true;
        List<List<int>> previousMoves = new List<List<int>>();
        int iterations = 0;
        while (!Traversed(met))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
            if (Possible(met, x, y))
            {
                met[x, y] = true;
                if (x == 0 && y == 0)//top left corner
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 2); //what if it is solvable? im checking if the next moves are NOT solvable, which means I will never get out of the for loop
                    if (temp == 0 && met[1, 0] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int>{ x, y});
                        Destroy(arr[1, 0]);
                        x++;
                    }
                    else if (met[0, 1] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr2[1, 0]);
                        y++;
                    }
                }
                else if (x == n - 1 && y == 0) //top right corner
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 2);
                    if (temp == 0 && met[x - 1, 0] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr[n - 1, 0]);
                        x--;
                    }
                    else if (met[x, 1] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr2[1, x]);
                        y++;
                    }
                }
                else if (x == 0 && y == n - 1) //bottom left corner
                {

                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 2);
                    if (temp == 0 && met[0, y - 1] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr2[n - 1, 0]);
                        y--;
                    }
                    else if (met[1, y] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr[1, n - 1]);
                        x++;
                    }
                }
                else if (x == n - 1 && y == n - 1) //bottom right corner
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 2);
                    if (temp == 0 && met[x, y - 1] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr2[n - 1, n - 1]);
                        y--;
                    }
                    else if (met[x - 1, y] == false)
                    {
                        previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                        Destroy(arr[n - 1, n - 1]);
                        x--;
                    }
                }
                else if (y == 0) //top row
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 3);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (met[x, 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[1, x]);
                                y++;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (met[x - 1, 0] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x, 0]);
                                x--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (met[x + 1, 0] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x + 1, 0]);
                                x++;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (y == n - 1) //bottom row
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 3);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (met[x, y - 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y, x]);
                                y--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (met[x - 1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x, y]);
                                x--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (met[x + 1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x + 1, y]);
                                x++;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (x == 0) //left column
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 3);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (met[0, y - 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y, 0]);
                                y--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (met[0, y + 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y + 1, 0]);
                                y++;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (met[1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[1, y]);
                                x++;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (x == n - 1) //right column
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 3);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (met[x, y - 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y, x]);
                                y--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (met[x, y + 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y + 1, x]);
                                y++;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (met[x - 1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x, y]);
                                x--;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int temp = Random.Range(0, 4);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (met[x, y - 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y, x]);
                                y--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (met[x, y + 1] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr2[y + 1, x]);
                                y++;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (met[x - 1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x, y]);
                                x--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (met[x + 1, y] == false)
                            {
                                previousMoves.Add(new List<int> { x, y });
                                Destroy(arr[x + 1, y]);
                                x++;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                x = previousMoves[previousMoves.Count - 1][0];
                y = previousMoves[previousMoves.Count - 1][1];
                //Debug.Log(x + " " + y);
                previousMoves.RemoveAt(previousMoves.Count - 1);
            }

            string temp2 = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < previousMoves.Count; i++)
            {
                temp2 += previousMoves[i][0] + " " + previousMoves[i][1] + " ";
            }

            Debug.Log(temp2);

            iterations++;
            if (iterations == 1000)
            {
                Debug.Log("break");
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < n + 1; i2++) //giving them a boxcollider component
            for (int j2 = 0; j2 < n; j2++)
            {
                if (arr[i2, j2] != null)
                    arr[i2, j2].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                if (arr2[i2, j2] != null)
                    arr2[i2, j2].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
            }
    }
```

I'm trying to generate this maze using the concept of depth first search. I've already generated the grid in another method. I start off in a random place in the grid, and the randomly go up, left, right, or down. I also keep track and make sure that I don't visit the same place in the cell with met[x, y] = true;
If there's no other place to go, I check that previous cells that I've visited through previousMoves. Traversed(met) simply checks if all the cells are visited.
The problem is that my maze generator gets stuck when it's backtracking multiple cells. Here's a picture of what is happening:
[image]

The console is printing out the values of previousMoves, or the previous cells visited. What I'm highlighting in red is where the maze generator is at.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Hopefully you get an idea of what's happening. It seems that the maze generator gets stuck when a cell is surrounded by cells that have already been visited and it doesn't know what to do. The code in charge of that is the else statement for if (Possible(...)). I'm not sure what I did wrong there. I forgot to mention that Possible simply checks if the cells above, below, to the left, and to the right are all visited.

Comment: Go back to the lat point that hasn’t got something in all directions?

Comment: Well it's supposed to eventually do that. It will keep (at least it's supposed to) going through previousMoves until it finds a point that "hasn't got something in all directions."

Comment: I did a room generator which could be argued can be a maze generator too in that it had a range of rooms. It could be long and thin or short and fat and had rooms to work from so 4 single exit options pairs, 3 exits and 1 all 4. If you work backwards you may have to work back 100 moves but that should still be a quick process

Answer (score 0):

`met[x,y] = true` should've been above the `if (Possible(...))` statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).